# Projections onto a subspace (orthogonal vs. non-orthogonal matrix vs. basis matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

> $A$ is our matrix
>
> $B$ is our basis for the matrix $A$
>
> $Q$ is orthogonal basis for matrix $A$
>
> $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

Is the following true:

$Px=(QQ^T)x=(B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T)x$

In plain English:

When I project onto a subspace, it doesn't matter what matrix I use, as long as their span is equal, meaning they span the same subspace.

I'm asking because sometimes there are less columns in $B$ and $Q$, than in $A$, so calculations are easier.

I'm an amateur mathematician, so I apologize if my wording is not correct.

Comment: The answer is yes.  In short, the projection onto a subspace depends only on which subspace you're projecting onto

Comment: Thank you for the reply

Comment: I should specify the *orthogonal* projection onto a subspace depends only on the choice of subspace

Comment: Would you mind sketching a simple proof? Not that i dont believe you, I just like proofs :)

Comment: What do you mean by a basis for a matrix? A vector space has a basis. A matrix is not a vector space.

Comment: Basis for the column space of matrix A.

Comment: I did derive the above result, but I'm not happy with assumtions I have to make intuitively.

Comment: There are many ways to project, say, ${\bf R}^2$ onto the $x$-axis. E.g., you can use $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$, but you can also use $\pmatrix{1&-1\cr0&0\cr}$. Of course you get different answers, depending on which projection matrix you use. But maybe that's not what you are asking.